# Why escape characters are not allowed in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, escaping, html-escape-characters, strict-mode

Why is escape characters not allowed in [javascript strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)?

```js
"use strict";

var y = \010; //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

```html
<h1>Check browser console for errors</h1>
```

Comment: Because in general, octals do more harm than good. According to your link, "*Octal syntax isn't part of ECMAScript 5*" in the first place, so browsers are free to not support it...

Comment: @DCoder I narrowed the question to escapes only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same reasoning applies as with octal numbers - these days, octal escapes are somewhat exotic. Also, "strict mode" is supposed to be useful, reliable and cross-browser compatible, and formally allowing optional extensions to it would set a bad precedent. But that's just my opinion. Are you asking out of curiosity, or because of a practical problem?

Comment: @DCoder I just began learning javascript so it's out of curiosity ;)